# Add hover event on intersecting sections of SVG graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bhyt7L5z/

I have 5 ellipse intersecting each other. I want to capture hover event on intersecting areas and show corresponding data in tool-tip.
ASomething like :

```
    $('paths').hover(function(e) {
        console.log('show content related to intersection');
    });
```

Can anyone give me pointers on how to do this.

Is there any chart available in JavaScript which gives interactive elliptical venn diagram

Regards

Answer (score 0):

just append `.attr('id','ellipse1')` for each of you ellipse and now you can use

```
 $('#ellipse1').hover(function(e) {
        console.log('show content related to intersection');
    });
```

code from you jsfiddle:

```js
var width = 450,
   height = 400


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


svg.append("svg:ellipse")
.attr("cx", 200)
.attr("cy", 200)
.attr("rx", 50)
.attr("ry",100)
.style("fill", 'rgba(108,255,108,0.4)')
.style("stroke", "#777")
.style("stroke-width", '1px')
.style("transform", 'rotate(30deg)')
.style("transform-origin", "50% 50%")
.attr("id","ellipse1")
.attr("data-toggle","tooltip")
.attr("title","ellipse1")


svg.append("svg:ellipse")
.attr("cx", 200)
.attr("cy", 200)
.attr("rx", 50)
.attr("ry",100)
.style("fill", 'rgba(168,255,168,0.4)')
.style("stroke", "#777")
.style("stroke-width", '1px')
.style("transform", 'rotate(70deg)')
.style("transform-origin", "50% 50%")
.attr("id","ellipse2")
.attr("data-toggle","tooltip")
.attr("title","ellipse2")

svg.append("svg:ellipse")
.attr("cx", 200)
.attr("cy", 200)
.attr("rx", 50)
.attr("ry",100)
.style("fill", 'rgba(148,255,148,0.4)')
.style("stroke", "#777")
.style("stroke-width", '1px')
.style("transform", 'rotate(110deg)')
.style("transform-origin", "50% 50%")
.attr("id","ellipse3")
.attr("data-toggle","tooltip")
.attr("title","ellipse3")

svg.append("svg:ellipse")
.attr("cx", 200)
.attr("cy", 200)
.attr("rx", 50)
.attr("ry",100)
.style("fill", 'rgba(128,255,128,0.4)')
.style("stroke", "#777")
.style("stroke-width", '1px')
.style("transform", 'rotate(140deg)')
.style("transform-origin", "50% 50%")
.attr("id","ellipse4")
.attr("data-toggle","tooltip")
.attr("title","ellipse4")
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

```css
svg { 
    border:1px dotted #000; 
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I need to hover intersection area
Once hovered over intersection I need to show relevant data

Comment: i added a bootstrap tooltip just to show the possible

Comment: Just to simplify my question, if two ellipse intersect, they will have some common area. I need to highlight this area.

eg: First eclipse : eclipse1 & second  : eclipse2
If user hovers over the intersection, I need to highlight that area and show which eclipses intersect.